# Getting OpenGL context newer than 2.1 with Qt 4 and Mavericks

Tags: macos, qt, opengl, qt4, pyside

I'm having difficulty creating an OpenGL context newer than 2.1 (Mac OS 10.9.1, Qt 4.8.5, PySide 1.2.1).  Minimal example code is given below; it produces a 2.1 context rather than 3.2 or higher.

The code is based on [this tutorial](http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_use_OpenGL_Core_Profile_with_Qt); the tutorial's sample C++ code also fails when run on my machine.

This issue might be related to [this bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-36816): `QGLFormat.openGLVersionFlags()` returns `0x7f` (indicating compatability up to OpenGL 2.1 but no later).

Is there something that I'm missing, or is it hopeless until that bug is fixed?

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtOpenGL
from OpenGL.GL import *

class Canvas(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        format = QtOpenGL.QGLFormat()
        format.setVersion(3, 2)
        format.setProfile(QtOpenGL.QGLFormat.CoreProfile)
        super(Canvas, self).__init__(format, parent)

    def initializeGL(self): print glGetString(GL_VERSION)

    def paintGL(self):      pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication("test")
    canvas = Canvas()
    canvas.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Can you try either with 4.8 from git, or with Qt 5.2.1 or qtbase from the release branch?

Comment: can you try on C++ firstly and then on python? Just open some examples which may accompanied with Qt.

Comment: [This tutorial's](http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_use_OpenGL_Core_Profile_with_Qt) C++ code fails for the same reason (a 2.1 context is generated, so the GLSL shader fails to compile).